# Regular page taking styles in summernote div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, codeigniter

So I am trying to edit an email format pulled from a database in a summernote div.

That is all working just fine. Except when I go to load the page this is all on, that pages takes the css styles of the style tags in the email. The following code I have is as follows:

```
<div class="tab-pane" id="emails">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Default Email Template</label>
        <?php echo form_textarea('email_template', $this->settings_m->get_setting('email_template'), 'class="form-control summernote"'); ?>
    </div>
</div>


<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.summernote').summernote();
});

</script>
```

How do I `escape` all tags within the email but still maintain the look of the email inside the summernote div? I want to do this so the email maintains it's appearance, as well as the page it sits on.